# Subsetting dataframe with grep

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have following data

```
Sample_ID<-c("a1_01_01","a2_03_03","a3_07_07","a4_09_09","a5_10_10","a6_21_21")
Sex<-c(M, M, F, F, M, NM)
DF1<-data.frame(Sample_ID,Sex)
```

I want to subset above df in the basis of following list.

```
Excluded <-c(a1_01, a3_07, a5_10)
```

I am using this code to execute

```
Newdf<-subset(DF1,Sample_ID %in% Excluded)
```

but its not working as you can see the `Excluded` and `Sample_ID` are not exactly same but their initials are similar. I have an idea that i need to pipe my R command with `grep` but couldnot figure out how to. Can someone please help me or if there is any other better simple way.

Comment: `DF1[ ! grepl("a1_01", DF1$Sample_ID), ]` will start you off. The line `Excluded <- ...` won't work because you haven't put your strings inside quotation marks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```r
DF1[!grepl(paste(Excluded, collapse = "|"), DF1$Sample_ID),]
#>   Sample_ID Sex
#> 2  a2_03_03   M
#> 4  a4_09_09   F
#> 6  a6_21_21  NM
```

This works by creating a regex that looks for *any* of the strings in `Example` and excludes them with logical negation and subsetting.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, `tidyverse`-based:

```r
library(tidyverse)

Sample_ID <- c("a1_01_01","a2_03_03","a3_07_07","a4_09_09","a5_10_10","a6_21_21")
Sex<-c("M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "M")
DF1<-data.frame(Sample_ID,Sex)

Excluded <-c("a1_01", "a3_07", "a5_10")

DF1 %>% 
  filter(!str_remove(Sample_ID, "_\\d{2}$") %in% Excluded)

#>   Sample_ID Sex
#> 1  a2_03_03   M
#> 2  a4_09_09   F
#> 3  a6_21_21   M
```

Comment: What does ""_\\d{2}$"" means here?

Comment: Each `Sample_ID` is longer than each element of `Excluded`. Then, the last part of each `Sample_ID` needs to be removed before comparison with `Excluded`. `_\\d{2}$` means  `_` followed by a number with two digits at the end of each `Sample_ID`.